# How to get historical price of options with strike price Y relative to being set at day X in python?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, algorithmic-trading

I've recently been using yahoofinance to backtest a trading algorithm I made. The problem is, there are certain elements that I am trying to code in the algorithm that should be easily possible, but nowhere on google, documentation, stack overflow, medium, etc tells how to code it.

The issue I cant seem how to do:
Get the historical option price of a stock with strike price X from the PERSPECTIVE of 30 days before the strike.

I can do the first, half, but not the second.

Here are some things I have tried that got no luck:

```
                   # option_price = option_chain[option_chain['contractSymbol'] == "AAPL231020C00140000"]["lastPrice"].iloc[0]
                    
                    

                    expiration_date = indicatordf['Date'] + dt.timedelta(days=30)
                    print(expiration_date)
                    option_price = get_historical_option_price(tickerName, expiration_date)  

def get_historical_option_priceAtExp(ticker, expiration_date, option_type="call", strike="at-the-money"):
    df = yf.download(ticker, period="1d", interval="1m", expiration_date=expiration_date)
    df = df.loc[(df["Option Type"] == option_type) & (df["Strike"] == strike)]
    df = df.loc[df["Expiration Date"] == expiration_date]
    return df.iloc[-1, 0]
```

I have experimented and trial and errored several times to see what works and what doesn't. Does anyone know how to code this?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in simple terms, saying "I can do the first, half, but not the second." isn't a lot of help.

Comment: Also,please format you code so that it appears correct in your question. And make sure your code actually runs.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime


def get_option_data(stock_symbol, expiration_date, option_type, strike):
    stock = yf.Ticker(stock_symbol)
    option_chain = stock.option_chain(expiration_date)
    options = getattr(option_chain, "calls" if option_type.startswith("call") else "puts")
    option_data = options[options["strike"] == strike]
    return option_data


def get_option_history_data(contract_symbol, days_before_expiration=30):
    option = yf.Ticker(contract_symbol)
    option_info = option.info
    option_expiration_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(option_info["expireDate"])

    start_date = option_expiration_date - datetime.timedelta(days=days_before_expiration)
    option_history = option.history(start=start_date)
    return option_history


def main(*args):
    # Example:
    stock_symbol = "AAPL"
    expiration_date = "2023-10-27"
    expiration_date = None
    option_type = "call"
    strike = 170.0

    option_data = get_option_data(stock_symbol, expiration_date, option_type, strike)
    for i, od in option_data.iterrows():
        contract_symbol = od["contractSymbol"]
        option_history = get_option_history_data(contract_symbol)
        first_option_history = option_history.iloc[0]
        first_option_history_date = option_history.index[0]
        first_option_history_close = first_option_history["Close"]
        print("For {}, the closing price was ${:.2f} on {}.".format(
            contract_symbol,
            first_option_history_close,
            first_option_history_date
        ))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

> For AAPL231027C00170000, the closing price was $5.40 on 2023-09-27
> 00:00:00-04:00.